# Generics - compiler inconsistency [jdk 1.8.0_162]

Tags: java, generics, java-8, compiler-errors

I came across a problem with generics which keeps me puzzled of how the compiler actually deals with generic types. Consider the following:

```
// simple interface to make it a MCVE
static interface A<F, S> {
    public F getF();    
    public S getS();
}

static <V, S> Comparator<A<V, S>> wrap(Comparator<S> c) {
    return (L, R) -> c.compare(L.getS(), R.getS());
}
```

The following will not compile because both generic types are reduced to `Object` when calling `thenComparing`:

```
Comparator<A<String, Integer>> c = wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R))
    .thenComparing(wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R)));
```

But if I break them up like the following example, everything compiles (and runs) correctly:

```
Comparator<A<String, Integer>> c = wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R));
c = c.thenComparing(wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R)));
```

So the question is: *what happens here?* I suspect this is due to some weird behavior of the compiler rather than intended language specification? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second attempt compiles correctly, because you specified the type of a variable yourself, telling the compiler what it is, because compiler does not have enough information to figure it out.

Look at this simplified example, it's from `vavr` (great by the way). There is a `Try<T>` class that represents a result of some operation. Generic parameter `T` is the type of that result. There is a static factory to create a failure immediately, meaning we have no result here, but the generic parameter is still there:

```java
static <T> Try<T> failure(Throwable exception) {
    return new Try.Failure(exception);
}
```

Where does the `T` come from here? The usage looks like this:

```
public Try<WeakHashMap> method() {
  return Try.failure(new IllegalArgumentException("Some message"));
}
```

The `Try<WeakHashMap>` here is my choice, not the compilers, you can actually put anything you want in there because you are choosing the type.

The same thing in your example, the `Comparator` has generic parameter `String` only, because you specified it and compiler agreed to it (like with `Try<WeakHashMap>`). When you added a chained call you forced the compiler to infer the type itself, and it was `Object`, because what another type it could have been?

What else you can do (notice the `Testing.<String, Integer>wrap`):

```
public class Testing {
  static interface A<F, S> {
    public F getF();
    public S getS();
  }

  static <V, S> Comparator<A<V, S>> wrap(Comparator<S> c) {
    return (L, R) -> c.compare(L.getS(), R.getS());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<A<String, Integer>> comp = Testing.<String, Integer>wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R))
      .thenComparing(wrap((L, R) -> Integer.compare(L, R)));
  }
}
```

Comment: I get that part, sounds quit logical. And thanks for the one-liner solution. Now I know I didn't mentioned it, but why doesn't casting work in this case? As you would essentially help the compiler inderstand your intentions in (to me) the same way as the double assigning/breaking up mentioned in my question?

Comment: Because it would already be `Comparator<A<Object, Object>>` and you would like to cast it, which is impossible. It's like casting `List<Integer>` to `List<Number>` - if that was possible you could end up with `List<Integer>` having Longs (or anything, since you could cast it to List<Object> too)

Comment: I guese thats how the compiler evaluates it indeed (first resolving, than casting). Still quit strange how 'splitting' would 'solve' it then (as that would also be casted afterwards, right?)

Comment: Splitting solves it, because there is no cast - the method returns `Comparator<A<String, Integer>>` already, because you provided the type during the assignment, compiler figured it out. With casting, method returns `Comparator<A<Object,Object>>` and then you try to cast. That's why this syntax (`Testing.<String, Integer>`) exists, to avoid casting afterwards.

Comment: No cast at all? Then I think I'll need to consult some byte-code examples to see what actually happens at those moments. Thanks for the extra information, today I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make one central piece of information more visible, "chained call":

In anything of the form `T t = m1().m2()` everything left of the last dot will have limited type inference with no [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types). The target type `T` can only help to infer `m2()`, not `m1()`.

This is a deliberate choice in the language design, in order to keep the complexity at bay. In this approach inferring the type of `m1()` must complete before starting to infer the type for `m2()` *(otherwise, where would you search for method m2?)*.